# Show that $\phi(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} a_n z^n + \dfrac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_{\Gamma} \dfrac{\phi(w) z^N}{w^N (w-z)}dw.$

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification, proof-explanation, residue-calculus

In Section 4.16. of Titchmarsh's book *The Theory of the Riemann Zeta-Function* it is written that for $\phi(z)= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n z^n$, $$\phi(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} a_n z^n + \dfrac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_{\Gamma} \dfrac{\phi(w) z^N}{w^N (w-z)}dw$$ holds, where $\Gamma$ is a counter including the points $0$ and $z$.

How this equation is true? By substitution of $\phi(w)$ into the integrand one gets $$\dfrac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_{\Gamma} \dfrac{\phi(w) z^N}{w^N (w-z)}dw = \dfrac{1}{2 \pi i} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \int_{\Gamma} \dfrac{a_n w^n z^N}{w^N (w-z)}dw = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n z^n,$$ by calculus of residues (considering the coefficient of $(w-z)^{-1}$); however, I was expecting to arrive at $\sum_{n=N}^{\infty} a_n z^n$. I think existence of $z^N$ in the integrand is a typo, am I right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Cauchy's integral formula, we have

$$
\phi(z)={1\over2\pi i}\int_\Gamma{\phi(w)\over w-z}\mathrm dw.
$$

Using the properties of the geometric series, there is

\begin{aligned}
{1\over w-z}
&={1\over w}\cdot{1\over 1-z/w}=\frac1w\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}\left(\frac zw\right)^n+\frac1w\cdot{(z/w)^N\over 1-z/w} \\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}{z^n\over w^{n+1}}+{z^N\over w^N(w-z)}.
\end{aligned}

Notice that

$$
a_n={1\over2\pi i}\int_\Gamma{\phi(w)\over w^{n+1}}
\mathrm dw,
$$

so we conclude that

$$
\phi(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}a_nz^n+{1\over2\pi i}\int_\Gamma{\phi(w)z^N\over w^N(w-z)}\mathrm dw.
$$